# File download is damaged from PHP, uploads fine

Tags: php, file-io, download

When I upload files to my server from the site it works fine. However, when I try to download them the file is damaged every time. If I open up the file manager on my server I can download the files through this, they work fine. I know the file is uploaded ok, it seems to be an error with the download process.

The files are saved on my server named by their ID in the table, followed by their extension. The name is retrieved from the database and that is used when downloading.

```
id  |  userid  |  filename   |   extension  |  size
1       2         test.jpeg       jpeg         123456

//the extension column is just for testing, yes I know it's redundant
```

test.jpeg would be saved on my server as 1.jpeg.

```
//this is the very first bit of code on the page aside from starting the session
if(isset($_POST['downloadFile'])){
    $file = new fileprocessing;
    $fileID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hiddenFileDownload']);
    $file->serveFile($fileID); 
}
```

Here is the serveFile function which find the file and allows the user to download it

```
function serveFile($fileID){
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from files where id = '$fileID'");
    $file = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $ext = $file['extension'];

    header('Content-type: image/x-generic'); //I'm trying jpegs only right now

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file['filename'].".".$ext.'" ');

    readfile('/home/.../public_html/user_files/'. $fileID.".".$ext.' ');
}
```

When the file is downloaded it has the correct name. I'm not sure where this is going wrong. Am I not opening the file properly?

**edit - adjusted my extension in my servefile function**

Comment: Why does your literal path have a `.../` in it?

Comment: It's a few folders deep, just removed it for the sake of readability.

Comment: @user1104854 Have you got any invisible leading whitespace in your file? BOMs?

Comment: The file is a jpeg, so unless you're talking about the name there is no whitespace. What are BOMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As weird as this sounds, I have had issues with viewing ".jpeg" file extensions in the past (i have a site where people have to upload images for products). It is possible however to rename the extension to ".jpg" and view the same file without any interuption. You might try renaming ".jpeg" extensions to ".jpg" when you upload then see if the results of downloading/viewing doesn't change.

Comment: since you have the extension, can you not modify the header "content-type" to "image/$extension"

Comment: I figured it out. It wasn't grabbing the correct file. I forgot that I removed the "extension" column so I was looking for something that wasn't there. Thanks for the tips, I probably wouldn't have even thought to look there if you hadn't mentioned it.